# C# Filter Tuple and Remove cast

Tags: c#, .net, list, tuples

I have a method that will bring in a list of strings and an id,
I have to return a tuple that will contain a list of strings and id, the tuple needs to be filtered and only return one string and one id and they cannot be the same
what I am stuck on is how to get rid of the cast on return and i want to make sure each string that i am returning has the right associated id with it.

```
 public static List<(string,int)> ModifiedData(List<string?> changedData, int? id)
 {
     //declare a tuple to keep track of all changes and id
     var result = new List<(string change, int? cId)>();
     if (changedData != null)
     {
         foreach (var change in changedData)
         {
             //add the change and id to a list of tuples
             result.Add((change, id));
         }
     }
        
     //delete all of the same instances in the array and return and array
     var filteredChanges = result.Select(x => (x.change, x.cId)).Distinct();

     //return the tuple** how can i also get rid of this cast
     return (List<(string, int)>)filteredChanges;
 }
```

Comment: 1) Why are you returning `int` if the input is `int?`? 2) It looks like you could just filter the `List<string?>` argument first (i.e., call `Distinct()` on it) and then construct your list of tuple.

Comment: The whole thing can be shortened to something like `changedData.Distinct().Select(s => (s, id)).ToList();`, but obviously, that will produce a `List<(string?, int?)>`, not a `List<(string, int)>`. Do you also want to filter out nulls?

Comment: originally i had it as `var filteredChanges = result.Select(x => x.change).Distinct(); return filteredChanges.ToList()`

Comment: this works after making the id not null `var filteredChanges = result.Select(x => (x.change,id)).Distinct(); return filteredChanges.ToList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your cast would throw an exception at runtime, since it's not a list.

You could simplify your code significanly:

```
public static List<(string, int)> ModifiedData(List<string?> changedData, int? id)
{
    return changedData?
        .Select(s => (s, id.GetValueOrDefault()))
        .Distinct()
        .ToList() ?? new List<(string, int)>(0);
}
```

However, maybe you want to add null checks for the string and/or the id. You could add a `Where`:

```
return changedData?
    .Where(s => s != null)
    .Select(s => (s, id.GetValueOrDefault()))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList() ?? new List<(string, int)>(0);
```